# Как в c# получить все теги где нет вложенных тегов для html документа?

Tags: c#, html

Пример html документа с вложенными тегами в тегах

```
<div>
   <p>text1</p>
   <p>text2<p>
</div>
```

или для

```
<div>
   <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
   <p>text2</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

для обоих случаев нужно получить

```
array = {
'<p>text1<p>',
'<p>text2<p>'
}
```

то есть - получить все теги где нет вложенных тегов
название всех (и вложенных) тегов может быть всегда разное

Comment: Есть библиотека Xnet, в ней имеется расширяющий метод для string Substrings возвращающий массив строк, в качестве параметров принимает начало строки и ее конец, а затем проверить регуляркой каждый элемент массива и подходящие запиши в другой массив

Comment: @prog432, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю сейчас все набегут и скажут почему не стоит парсить html регулярками)Как вот тут, например): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
Я думаю для этой задачи подойдет стандартный xml парсер вроде HtmlAgilityPack с методом поиска по тому же XPath например.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить все текстовые XML-узлы. Это можно сделать с помощью Linq To Xml и поиску по XPath:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

// - - - - - - - -

var xml = XElement.Parse("<div><p>text1</p><p>text2</p></div>");
var result = ((IEnumerable)xml.XPathEvaluate("//*/text()"))
                .OfType<XText>()
                .Select(node => node.Parent.ToString())
                .ToArray();
```

Несколько замечаний по примерам из вопроса:

1. В первом html-примере не закрыт второй тег `<p>`.
2. Второй документ содержит два корневых элемента. Это невалидный xml-документ. Всегда должен быть только один корневой элемент.